# (int) does not type-convert multiplication result correctly

Tags: php, type-conversion, integer

If I use (int) to convert a product between a float  type variable and an integer, the result is not what I expect it to. Please see my code.

The expectation is that the result is 4090270, not 4090269

(int)(4090270.0) works correctly

```
$amount = 40902.70; // Same for  40902.20
$amount= (int)($amount*100);
echo $amount; /// Output :  4090269
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never cast an unknown fraction to integer, as this can sometimes lead to unexpected results.

According to PHP documentation

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format, which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like 7.9999999999999991118....

See this [**reference**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
$amount = 40902.70; // Same for  40902.20
$amounts= intval(strval($amount*100));;
echo $amounts;
```

Note: **intval and int converts doubles to integers by truncating the fractional component of the number.**

For more info check : [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
$test1 = intVal(1999);

$amount = 19.99 * 100;
$test2 = intVal($amount);
$test3 = intVal("$amount");

echo $test1 . "<br />\n";
echo $test2 . "<br />\n";
echo $test3 . "<br />\n";

expected output:
1999
1999
1999

actual output
1999
1998
1999
```

Appears to be a floating point issue, but the number 1999 is the only number that I was able to get to do this.  19.99 is the price of many things, and for our purpose we must pass it as 1999 instead of 19.99.